# Ошибка запуска grunt build

Tags: node.js, windows

```
    Jekyll output:
Configuration file: _config.yml
Configuration file: _config.build.yml
            Source: app
       Destination: dist
      Generating... Warning: Command failed: DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
error: Invalid argument - D:/Vargant/Code/root.app/dist/D:. Use --trace to view backtrace
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Получаю такую ошибку при запуске на Windows. Что-то не так, видимо, с путями, но не нашел, где править.

Comment: Вам вряд ли ответят, так-как Yeoman мало кто использует... Или мало кто ПОКА использует. У меня были проблемы с запуском его на windows, неделю не мог справиться и пришлось начинать осваивать ubuntu. Хотя после того, как я разобрался с ubuntu оказалось, что это был ,fu от разработчиков и они его исправили.  
А Вы консоль от администратора запускаете? yml нужно устанавливать, чтобы он работал? Если да, то у Вас он установлен?

Comment: Виртуальный сервер поднимал с помощью vagrant. Там запускается все без проблем, с небольшими танцами с бубнами при установке node.js. Но захотелось то же самое сделать в винде. Потратил сегодня целый день, но так и не докопался. Jekyll и Grunt сами по себе работают. 
Про yml ничего не слышал. 
Консоль от администратора запускать совершенно не нужно. 
Пишут, что можно потанцевать с CygWin, но пока не очень хочется.

Comment: Честно сказать, я сам плохо понимаю, но из собственного опыта обратил бы внимание на следующее - когда ставишь yo, то многие зависимости для windows выглядят, как "нечто, что хочет поставиться" и вот для этого может ( у меня так было ) потребоваться запустить консоль от админа. Так же у меня были проблемы, так-как какой-то генератор был написан на питоне, а у меня он не был установлен. И вот у Вас я увидел файлы с разрешением .yml и возможно, это нечто схожее с питоном.

Comment: Кстати говоря, только сейчас я обратил на это внимание. Гугл говорит, что это парсер для питона. 
Сейчас попробую его поставить. Питон и руби стояли давно. Правда со вторыми руби тоже возникли проблемы, пришлось откатиться до 1.9.3p545 и питон 2.7.7.
И не помню, что бы я что то ставил от админа. В основном это гемы или клоны гита.